# setOnMouseMoved between specific x

Tags: javafx

I am making the game Breakout and want to move the paddle by it following my mouse-movements. When the mouse leaves my `AnchorPane` named `windowPane`, the paddle is halfway gone, too. I would like to ask for help: how do I make the paddle not follow the mouse any longer when I reach the bounds of my pane?

```
windowPane.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        /**move Paddle with mouse *@author Can @author SziSzi */

        paddle.setLayoutX(event.getY());
        paddle.setLayoutX(event.getX()- paddle.getWidth()/2);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check, if the position would make the paddle violate the bounds of the pane:

```
double h = paddle.getHeight();
double pW = paddle.getWidth() / 2;

double x = event.getX();
double y = event.getY();

if (x >= pW && x + pW <= windowPane.getWidth() && y + h <= windowPane.getHeight()) {
    paddle.setLayoutY(y);
    paddle.setLayoutX(x - pW);
} // otherwise ignore the event
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works wonderfully. I just had to take out the update of my paddle Layout in Y direction. ;) thanks